# Status Bar During App Showing Default.png

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, statusbar

I believe this is trivial, but I can't for the life of me, figure this out.
My app has a Black Translucent Status bar. However, when executing the app
(where Default.png is showing), the status bar shown is just a basic grey color.
I want this to be Black Translucent as well.

How?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try changing `UIStatusBarStyle` in `Info.plist`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your info.plist add a Status bar style with value UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I never knew about this key.